# I can't build apk flutter app. Java Error: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid

Tags: java, flutter, apk

I wanted to test my flutter app in phone. So I tried to build an apk. I ran this in app files:

```bash
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

Results:

```
 Building with sound null safety


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            4,0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

If I understood correctly it can't find Java. Because `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin` path is empty. I tried to uninstall and reinstall Java, but result is the same. How can I solve this and build apk for test in my phone?

Comment: @Lenny4 There is no file named jdk in C:\Program Files\Java\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only installed Java JRE (java runtime environment). Install complete java SDK. Add SDK path as JAVA_HOME variable in environment variables.

Comment: That is solved java error. But i take new error when build apk.  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Can Ahmet\StudioProjects\myapp\myapp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26                                                                                                                           Should i ask new questions? Do you have idea?

Comment: @CanKURT you should generate new question with code for "bild.gradle" file and complete error logs.